# jquerymobile css not compatible with swiper js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm creating a phonegap app with jquery mobile, and i have an splash screen, after five seconds, will slide to the swiper slide , here is the code:

index.html

```
  <!--splash-->
  <div data-role="page" id="page_splash">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/splash.js"></script>
      <div class="center"><img src="images/sample_icon.png"></div>
  </div>
  <!--end of splash-->
  <!--swpier-->
  <div data-role="none" id="page_swiper" style="display:none">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Swiper-3.1.0/swiper.min.css">

      <div class="swiper-container" data-role="none">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper" data-role="none">
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</span>
              <span class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</span>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      </div>

      <script src="js/Swiper-3.1.0/swiper.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true
        });

      </script>

  </div>
  <!--end of swpier-->
```

splash.js

```
$('#page_splash').live('pageshow',function(){
setTimeout(
  function()
  {
    //alert('test');
     //$('#page_swiper').show();
     $.mobile.changePage( $('#page_swiper'), { transition: "slide", reverse: true });

     //$('#page_swiper').hide();
     $('#page_swiper').show();
          $("#page_swiper").data("data-role", "none");
          $("#page_swiper").load();

     //do something special
  }, 5000);

})
```

The uncompatible means the swiper doesn't show all bullets relative to the number of slides, see the pic

[image]
 and i found that the problems will occur if i set the page_swiper  its data-role to "page".But Even i set the data-role (page_swiper) to none, if the code 
$.mobile.changePage( $('#page_swiper'), { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
once run, the page_swiper  seems its data-role will be changed to "page" automatically and the problem will occur again, How can i make the swiper work perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added `var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {`

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page_swiper', function() {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true
    });
}
```

solved the problem